# An Error of variable.split(',') is not a function

Tags: javascript

I have this as a result in my inspector
[image]

This is how I receive it from my signalr server

```
 /**
   * Tunnel to receive message from the server
   * @param serverMessage = message from the server
   */
  onMessageReceived(serverMessage: string) {
    console.log(serverMessage);
    const x = serverMessage.split(',');
    console.log(x);
    return serverMessage;
  }
```

I get the result seen in the image above but when I use the serverMessage.split(','), I get the error of "ERROR TypeError: serverMessage.split is not a function"

Can you please show me hot to make the result into an array? If you will notice the beginning of the image there is a number "(19477)". What is that? Is that a number of lines? Or is it the number of array items?

Comment: From your log, looks like `serverMessage` is an array, not a string.

Comment: It is an array, with 19477 elements in it.

Comment: The serverMessage is already an array of strings. And yes, the number is the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I guess split only works on strings, not arrays, or objects. The response from the server is not a string, hence, an error is thrown when split function is applied to a non string data type